# How to quickly format selected code in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

When input some code in orgmode, I can type:

`<s` <kbd>Tab</kbd>

and it expands to this:

`#+BEGIN_SRC` <kbd>cursor</kbd>

`#+END_SRC`

This is fine for writing something from scratch. But most of the time, I'd copy some paragraph which contains some code. (Code interposed in paragraphs).

In this scenario, after Tab, I have to select the code snippet, cut and paste them between BEGIN and END. Or cut the END_SRC, paste it at the end of the code.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

The ideal process would be:

1. Select some code
2. run a command, the code is well formatted by the BEGIN, END markdowns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that should do what you want. To use it, select a region, and run the command. It will handle putting in the `#+BEGIN_SRC` and `#+END_SRC` parts on new lines. It happens to leave you at the beginning of the source code block, but that could be changed.

```
(defun org-wrap-source ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (min (point) (mark)))
        (end (max (point) (mark))))
    (goto-char end)
    (unless (bolp)
      (newline))
    (insert "#+END_SRC\n")
    (goto-char start)
    (unless (bolp)
      (newline))
    (insert "#+BEGIN_SRC\n")))
```

You can bind this function to an appropriate key if you like.

Comment: Thank you. I modified it slightly to move the cursor after BEGIN_SRC (and a space) to let me specify what language the code is in. So that the syntax highlighting and indentation would be right. Added `    (backward-char)
    (insert " ")` after the last expression.

Answer (score 2):

This function can do it for you: from [chrisdone/chrisdone-emacs](https://github.com/chrisdone/chrisdone-emacs/blob/master/config/org.el)

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-#") 'org-begin-template)
(defun org-begin-template ()
  "Make a template at point."
  (interactive)
  (if (org-at-table-p)
      (call-interactively 'org-table-rotate-recalc-marks)
    (let* ((choices '(("s" . "SRC")
                      ("e" . "EXAMPLE")
                      ("q" . "QUOTE")
                      ("v" . "VERSE")
                      ("c" . "CENTER")
                      ("l" . "LaTeX")
                      ("h" . "HTML")
                      ("a" . "ASCII")))
           (key
            (key-description
             (vector
              (read-key
               (concat (propertize "Template type: " 'face 'minibuffer-prompt)
                       (mapconcat (lambda (choice)
                                    (concat (propertize (car choice) 'face 'font-lock-type-face)
                                            ": "
                                            (cdr choice)))
                                  choices
                                  ", ")))))))
      (let ((result (assoc key choices)))
        (when result
          (let ((choice (cdr result)))
            (cond
             ((region-active-p)
              (let ((start (region-beginning))
                    (end (region-end)))
                (goto-char end)
                (insert "\n#+END_" choice)
                (goto-char start)
                (insert "#+BEGIN_" choice "\n")))
             (t
              (insert "#+BEGIN_" choice "\n")
              (save-excursion (insert "\n#+END_" choice))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference:

- Add a template for the source block eg https://github.com/grettke/home/blob/master/ALEC.txt#L4334
- Select the code that you want to wrap
- Use `kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter` to record and automate your task

Reasons:

- I like the structure templates; they are easy to remember and I use them all of the time
- You can't automate something until you know what you want to do and the macro recorder makes that really easy